# Why does Python give "OSError: [Errno 36] File name too long" for filename shorter than filesystem's limit?

Tags: python, linux, filesystems, ext4

The following code yields an unexpected exception:

```
open("52bbe674cdc81d4140099b84fa69eea4249bcceee75bcbe4838d911ab076547cfdad3c1c5197752a98e5525fe76613dbe52dcdb1a9a397669babce0f101d010142cffa000000.csv", "w")
OSError: [Errno 36] File name too long: '52bbe674cdc81d4140099b84fa69eea4249bcceee75bcbe4838d911ab076547cfdad3c1c5197752a98e5525fe76613dbe52dcdb1a9a397669babce0f101d010142cffa000000.csv'
```

This is unexpected because my filesystem is ext4 which (according to Wikipedia) has a 255 byte filename length limit. The above filename has a length of 144.

So why does Python raise this exception when the filename length limit hasn't actually been exceeded?

Comment: Well, works for me on Python 3.5, ext4.

Comment: works for me on 2.7 and 3.4, what OS are you using?

Comment: Fedora 20, Python 3.3.2

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've found a solution. It turns out that I'm not dealing with pure ext4---it's actually ecryptfs layered atop ext4, carried over from a previous Ubuntu install. As suggested in an unaccepted answer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886640/ubuntu-encrypted-home-directory-errno-36-file-name-too-long) the ecryptfs layer imposes a limit of 143 characters to the filename length. A definitive answer to the file name length limit under ecryptfs can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32795/what-is-the-maximum-allowed-filename-and-folder-size-with-ecryptfs).